# Передача простых типов по ссылке

Tags: java

Как предавать переменные простых типов в методы, если нам необходимо изменить искомое значение. Классы обёртки не помогают, т.к они неизменяемы!!!

Comment: Никак, в Java нет передачи по ссылке.

Comment: Можно сделать свою обёртку, а можно передавать примитивы используя массив единичной длины

Comment: про свою обёрку я знал, а за массив единичной длины спасибо!!!! Кстати а возможно ли реализация такой структуры данных как бинарное дерево в JAVA, пытался перенести свою реализацию с с++ на джава, но ничего не вышло из-за вышеупомянутой проблемы

Comment: Не очень понятно. Вы хотите узнать, как называется тип `static`?

Comment: нет, насколько я понимаю static тут не при чём, вопрос был касаемо, передачи параметров методу, с последующим отражением изменений в самой передоваемой переменной(имеется в виду для просты типов, так как по умолчанию они передаются по значению, а не по ссылке)

Comment: В Java все параметры передаются по значению. Видимость изменения **состояния** параметра извне -- это не достаточное условие для того, чтобы говорить о передаче по ссылке. Вот Вы попробуйте в методе на параметре сделать `param = new ...` -- вне метода нового объекта Вы не увидите, а если бы параметр передавался по ссылке, то эти изменения были бы видны.